# Android Parse Image UPDATE

Tags: android, parse-platform

I found lot's of post regarding how to upload an image through parse. But I want to know how can I update and image (on an existing row)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Get a reference to the ParseObject. (You might need to download the ParseObject by using a ParseQuery if the object is in the server)
2. Set the same property to a different value. E.g
3. Save the ParseObject again.

> E.g: The following queries the cloud for a Person object.

We assume the Person object has the properties

- name
- image

Then it sets the new image and saves to the cloud.

```
ParseQuery query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Person");
    query.whereEqualTo("personName", "John");
    query.setLimit(1);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(List list, ParseException e) {}

        @Override
        public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {
            List<ParseObject> list = (List<ParseObject>)o;
            ParseObject john = list.get(0);

            byte[] data = <Byte array representation of the new image to upload>
            ParseFile fileObject = new ParseFile("newImage.jpg", data);
            john.put("image", fileObject);
            john.saveInBackground();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Getting an error saying java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.parse.ParseObject

Comment: In this line  ParseObject john = (ParseObject) o;

Comment: Ooppps... I'm sorry. I didn't check the code. The object 'o' is a list indeed. You have to get the first object of the list. I'll correct the code above too.

Comment: Hi @Bumba. Can you check now?

Comment: Perfect Thanks a lot